# GWT ClickListener or CLlickHandler does not work on IE Properly

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have One Panel which extends AbsolutePanel and every time when I add widget which has click handler it throws JS Exception. This happens only in IE 8 and 9.
Code:

```
  private static class MyCustomPanel extends AbsolutePanel {

  private MyCustomPanel (Element elem) {

     super(elem);
     onAttach();
  }
}
```

And then I use this MyCustomPanel to add some Widgets in Element from my DOM application

```
 final Panel panel = new MyCustomPanel (element);
        panel.add(mywidget); 

 Where mywidget is different widget which implements ClickListner, ClickHandler and so  on.... (In my case I have Scrollable Panel with different Widgets.)
    I get my element with this code: 

   private native static Element getServiceElement(String elementName)
 /*-{
    debugger;
    var element = $wnd.top.document.getElementById("div-"+elementName);

    if (element) {
        element.innerHTML = '';
    }
    return element;
}-*/;
This issue hapens only on IE8 and IE9 on FF and Chrome works fine.

JS Exception
```

[image]

```
Update!
```

I Found that the reason of failure is that GWT tries to addEventListener on my Element,       for some reason it thinks that my browser is IE6. Is there a way to force my panel to use attachEvent instead of addEventListener?

Comment: FYI, in IE, `.returnValue` is only called on `$wnd.event`. That'd mean somehow some code is called that expects to be called in response to an event, but is not (`$wnd.event` is `null`). HTH

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clue, I will investigate in this direction right now